# Visual Studio Web Reference rrrors

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, web-reference

I have a website solution that used to be managed using VS2008. Now since migrating to VS2010 I have noticed a long list of errors caused by auto generated WebReference code. The code generated is in C# and everything else on the solution is in VB.NET. All errors are syntax errors.

The website is not web project. I can compile successfully, but these errors showing in Error List window are starting to get on my nerves. It makes finding real errors a little tough among the piles of syntax errors from this webreference code.
I cannot even find this auto generated file on my solution. It lives in this folder:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\SolutionName\347ac797\7f99bbcc\Sources_App_WebReferences\

I have tried to delete the offending file, but when I recompile the file is generated back again in C#.

Any help to get rid of these errors is appreciated.

Comment: Delete the webreference will get rid of it's errors. However there reference was probably there for a reason.

Comment: how do I select which language the proxy class should be generated in?

Comment: I think you need to put it in an assembly of that language and and then reference the assembly.

Comment: Yes, looks like that's the only way. Unless I changed my website to web application project, which I do not want to go down that route. @PreetSangha Do you want to make that the answer so I can close this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put it in an assembly of that language and and then reference the assembly.